# How To Change Banner used By Spring Roo on Web Pages

Tags: spring-roo

Dear Sirs et Madames,
I am currently experimenting with Roo, and one thing I would like to change is the banner that Roo creates on the Roo-generated web interface, I would like to use a custom banner. I know I can do this by going to the '**webapp/images**' folder of the generated Roo project and replace the banner image with one of my own, but I want to know if I can make Roo *GENERATE* the web application with my banner from the start, rather than me having to go and fiddle with image files in the generated project...

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The default banner is yours to replace.

Feel free to modify, because it's meant to be modified.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to repackage org.springframework.roo.addon.web.mvc.jsp-xxx.jar
There you have all the images and default tags.

Answer (score 0):

No, Roo can't generate a project with a custom banner image.

Feel free to [log it](https://jira.springsource.org/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa) as an improvement request at our JIRA instance, however given the ease of replacing the default image manually, I can't see it getting much priority over the more highly-voted tickets.